# bash shell scripting: conditional string concatenation

Tags: bash, scripting, raspberry-pi, debian

I want to conditionally submit a text into another shell script. Meaning I want to replace "WARNING" in case deb=1 with "INFO":

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
...
if [[ $abc -lt 98 ]] || [[ $deb -eq 1 ]]
then 
    ./discord.sh --webhook-url=$url --text "WARNING: $abc"
fi
```

I also want to avoid another complete IF statement. I expect to have something like

```
deb=1 ? "INFO" : "WARNING"
```

Does that work? If yes, how would the complete statement look like? "--text ..."

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with an array index to match a numerical log-level with a name string:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

url=https://example.com/hook

logLevel=(WARNING INFO)

for abc in 97 98; do
  for deb in 0 1; do
    printf 'abc=%d, deb=%d:\n' $abc $deb
    (((i = 1 == deb) || 98 > abc)) &&
      echo ./discord.sh --webhook-url=$url --text "${logLevel[i]}: $abc"
  done
done
```

Output:

```
abc=97, deb=0:
./discord.sh --webhook-url=https://example.com/hook --text WARNING: 97
abc=97, deb=1:
./discord.sh --webhook-url=https://example.com/hook --text INFO: 97
abc=98, deb=0:
abc=98, deb=1:
./discord.sh --webhook-url=https://example.com/hook --text INFO: 98
```

Comment: `if [[ $abc -lt 98 ]] || [[ $deb -eq 1 ]]` is true when `abc==100` and `deb==1`. When fixed remove the `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
 [[ $abc -lt 98 ]] && {
   ./discord.sh --webhook-url=$url --text "$([[ $deb -eq 1 ]] && echo "INFO" || echo "WARNING"): $abc"
 }
```

Think of this as a alternative to `if` `then` `else` `fi` (the curly brackets are only neccesary if you have more commands, but I like to use it anyway, for readability (in some cases).

Basically it's

`[[ condition ]] && { commands if true } || { commands if false }`

Comment: When `abc==100` and `deb==1` you also want to call `discord.sh`

Comment: Yeah, this one works for me: `$([[ $deb -eq 1 ]] && echo 'INFO' || echo 'WARNING')`

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try:

```
if (( abc < 98 || deb == 1 )); then
    loglevel=$( (( deb == 1 )) && echo "INFO" || echo "WARNING" )
    ./discord.sh --webhook-url=$url --text "$loglevel: $abc"
fi
```

Comment: looks very good, thank you!

Comment: I've forgot to drop the `echo` command for the testing purpose. Now fixed.

Comment: `echo` is not needed unless you do NOT want the content to be word-split. I had a command "$([[ -n $1 ]] && echo "--profile $1")" and had to use `[[ -n $1 ]] && echo --profile $1` to get proper word splitting.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the answer of @tshiono is best. However, it becomes hard to read/debug.
Why not use a verbose solution?
When both conditions are true, you want to log with INFO.

```
if ((deb==1 )); then 
  ./discord.sh --webhook-url="$url" --text "INFO: $abc"
elif ((abc < 98)); then
  ./discord.sh --webhook-url="$url" --text "WARNING: $abc"
fi
```